# whats the purpose of using over and rank keywords in hive sql?

Tags: hadoop, hive

What is the meaning/purpose of using over and rank keywords in hive sql?

```
select rank() over (order by net_worth desc) as rank, name, net_worth from wealth order by rank, name;
+------+---------+---------------+
| rank | name    | net_worth     |
+------+---------+---------------+
| 1    | Solomon | 2000000000.00 |
| 2    | Croesus | 1000000000.00 |
| 2    | Midas   | 1000000000.00 |
| 4    | Crassus | 500000000.00  |
| 5    | Scrooge | 80000000.00   |
+------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The OVER clause is powerful in that you can have aggregates over different ranges ("windowing"), whether you use a GROUP BY or not

`OVER` clause defines a window or user-specified set of rows within a query result set. A window function then computes a value for each row in the window. You can use the `OVER` clause with functions to compute aggregated values such as moving averages, cumulative aggregates, running totals, or a top N per group results

Over  clause can be used in association with aggregate function and ranking function. The over clause determine the partitioning and ordering of the records before associating with aggregate or ranking function.

suppose you use only rank() function then how sql will understand on which bases rank will be calculated. example table have 3 columns name, net_worth and net_profit. Name with highest net_profit will be first rank. so you have to tell the sql that calculate rank on the bases of highest net_profit.

Answer (score 0):

**over()** works on a "**window**" of attributes.

In your example, **`select rank() over (order by net_worth desc)`**, you have instructed to rank the table with net_worth column in descending order. Due to that reason, ranking is done on descending order of net_worth.

over() is powerful it was used along with **`partition by`**.

Have a look at this [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/taylor22/entry/hive_0_11_may_15), which provides good examples to understand the concepts.

If you have sales table with Territory & Sales Amount, you can provide rank on order of Sales Amount Or create a partition for Territory and rank the Sales amount  with in a Territory.

Have a look at this [article](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) to get understanding on WindowingAndAnalytics. It will explain how to use aggregate functions in HiveQL.